# Get JOB_COMPLETION_INDEX on EKS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am new to Kubernetes and AWS and I have a problem. I am trying to run parallel Kubernetes jobs on an EKS cluster. How can I get the environment variable JOB_COMPLETION_INDEX?
I have tested my Java code before with Minikube "locally", there everything works fine. But when I switch to the EKS cluster, System.getenv("JOB_COMPLETION_INDEX") = null. What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

I used EKS version 1.21.2.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: calculator
  labels:
    jobgroup: calculator
spec:
  parallelism: 2
  completions: 4
  completionMode: Indexed
  template:
    metadata:
      name: calculator
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: calculater
          image: fbaensch/calculator_test:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a v1.22 beta feature which currently not available on EKS v1.21.x.

Comment: Checkout the roadmap [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/kubernetes-versions.html#kubernetes-release-calendar).

Comment: Thank you. But I will not wait until 17 March. So I will go for an external queue or so on EKS. And I will test it on GKE

Answer (score 0):

EKS don't support release **1.22**, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/kubernetes-versions.html

This feature only available in 1.22 K8s release

You can check issue status at : https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1397

K8s document : https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/19/introducing-indexed-jobs/

If you just want to try it on K8s, i would suggest checking out the GKE.

**GKE** Rapid channel has both **1.22 & 1.23** release option.

**GKE Rapid channel release notes** : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes-rapid